# NA values when converting character to timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp

I am getting an NA value when trying to convert a character time to atime stamp value

```
test = "27 Mar 2021 18:28:02"
```

I have tried to convert this to a timestamp using `strptime` and `as.POSIXct` but the value comes back as na.

```
as.POSIXct(test,format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" )

strptime(test, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: The format you specified does not correspond to your string. You have to specify the format of the input string. Try `strptime(test,format = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")`.

Comment: Using `lubridate::dmy_hms` works as well (`dmy_hms("27 Mar 2021 18:28:02")`)

Comment: You can read [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) to learn what the `%`-codes mean. In this case, `%m` is *"Month as decimal number (01-12)"* and `%b` is *"Abbreviated month name in the current locale ..."*. Also, your string has spaces and your `format=` has dashes, you need to pay attention to those details.

Comment: FYI, `strptime(..)` will return `POSIXlt` not `POSIXct`,use @nicola's code but replace `strptime` with `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: Thanks Nicola. That has resolved the issue. Thank you.